# Why Does Passing A StreamReader Between Methods Set It To the End of the Stream?

Tags: c#

I am working with some files downloaded from a web server.  They are small enough that they can be held in memory.  I have this working code:

```
public static Stream GetYAMLAsStream(string yamlfile)
    { byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yamlfile);
        MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length);
        Stream yamlstreamreader = stm;
        return yamlstreamreader;
    }
```

I then consume that stream in other parts of my program. I do this rather than passing a string because the string is a value type so I'd have multiple copies of it.   If I change the above code to:

```
 public static StreamReader GetYAMLAsStream(string yamlfile)
    {  byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yamlfile);
        MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length);
        return new StreamReader(stm);
    }
```

to return a StreamReader, when the StreamReader is passed to another method to be read, EndOfStream is set to true and an exception is thrown when I try to read the stream in the method that is using it.  Is this because C# reads it to the end to be able to pass it?  Since it's a reference type, shouldn't it just pass the reference to the StreamReader instance without having to read it?

I've added the code that calls the GetYAMLAsStream static function:

```
  foreach (DumpDecoderFileRecord snap in response)
            {
            Stream yamlstream = EcurepFunctions.GetYAMLAsStream(EcurepFunctions.GetYAMLAsString(snap.Number));
            foreach (YAMLSNAPData yaml in SVCUtilities.GetSVCClusterNames(snap.Number, yamlstream)) 
                {  
                    var ysnap = SnapData.Where(y => y.SnapDate == yaml.SnapDate && y.ClusterName == yaml.ClusterName);
                    if (ysnap.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        yaml.SnapNumber = snap.Number;
                        SnapData.Add(yaml);
                    }
                }
            }
```

here is the GetSVCClusterNames() that the stream is passed to.  When I had this defined to take a StreamReader, it threw an exception assigning readline and trying to read a line from the StreamReader - the stream had already been read to the end.

```
public static List<YAMLSNAPData> GetSVCClusterNames(string snapnumber, Stream yamlstream)
    {
        List<YAMLSNAPData> retVal = new List<YAMLSNAPData>();
        StreamReader yamlreader = new StreamReader(yamlstream);
        Match match;
        String NamePattern = @"(?<clustername>\w+):";
        string DatePattern = @"(?<date>'\d+.\d+')";
        bool capture = false;
        string clustername = "";
        string readline = yamlreader.ReadLine();
        YAMLSNAPData snapinfo = null;
        //cluster_to_version:

        while (!(readline.Contains("vrmf")))
        {
            if (readline.Contains("cluster_to_version")) { capture = true; readline = yamlreader.ReadLine(); }
            if (capture)
            {
                match = Regex.Match(readline, NamePattern);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    clustername = match.Groups["clustername"].Value.TrimEnd(':');
                    snapinfo = new YAMLSNAPData();
                    snapinfo.ClusterName = clustername;
                    retVal.Add(snapinfo);
                }

                match = Regex.Match(readline, DatePattern);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    string valtotrim = @"'";
                    char[] chartotrim = valtotrim.ToCharArray();
                    if (snapinfo != null)
                    {

                        string lsfabricdate = match.Groups["date"].Value.TrimEnd(chartotrim);
                        lsfabricdate = lsfabricdate.TrimStart(chartotrim);
                        snapinfo.SnapDate = lsfabricdate;
                    }

                }

            }

            readline = yamlreader.ReadLine();
        }

        return retVal;

    }
```

Comment: `string` is _not_ a value type.

Comment: this line of code is unnecessary: `Stream yamlstreamreader = stm`.  You can just return `stm` because a `MemoryStream`  derives from `Stream`

Comment: @xxbbcc, you're right it's not, but it behaves like a value type.

Comment: Just a random question - did you try marking the parameter as `ref` ?

Comment: No.  I shouldn't need to, since as far as I know it's already a reference type.  That's why I was attempting to use it instead of a string.  Yes, a string is a reference type but it behaves like a value type.

Comment: @DavidGreen it does not behave just like a value type, it is just immutable. If you pass it around the whole thing doesn't get copied over and over, only the reference is.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ERFbR8

Comment: In [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZTEsd9) you can see that it doesn't get read by just passing around the reference. I suspect that you are unknowingly reading the stream somewhere. Maybe by passing it to a Framework function that you didn't expect would read it. We'll need to see some more code to determine what's really going on.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels I added some more code, but I'll check and see if Im reading it somewhere.  I see your Fiddle is the opposite of what Im experiencing.

Comment: I see three lines with a `yamlreader.ReadLine()` on it. Which line does the Exception occur on? If it's not the first line. Are you sure that it hasn't just read a bunch of times, reached the end and is calling `yamlreader.ReadLine()` again?

Comment: @MatthijsWessels I figured it out.  You were correct, I had a ReadToEnd() in the code.  After running your Fiddle I went back and tried to recreate the exception in my code but couldn't. I'm refactoring this code so I can port it to a DLL for someone else to use. I did a line by line check and  realized that before the foreach(DumpDecoderFileRecord snap) line I have a commented out function that I no longer need that does a ReadToEnd() on the StreamReader.  When I added that back it broke again.    thanks for the help.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found it. About this question: Right now it pertains to a very specific problem in your code and it would be "too localized" to stay open as it won't have much value for anyone else. If you want to keep it open, try to rephrase the title/content to address a more generic problem. E.g. "Why is stream.EndOfStream true while I didn't use it yet" with code in the question where there's a non-obvious `ReadToEnd`. In that form, the question could be useful to others. The reason I guessed that's what happened in your case was because it has happened to me as well in the past :).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a specific error in my code.   It is a narrow focus that may not help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think passing A StreamReader between methods set it to the end of the stream the code below prints Hello World. 
Your function GetSVCClusterNames uses a Stream not a StreamReader. So I can't see exactly what is your point or where your code fails.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleStreamReaderTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static StreamReader GetYAMLAsStreamReader(string yamlfile)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yamlfile);
            MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length);
            return new StreamReader(stm);
        }


        static void UseStreamReader1(StreamReader b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.ReadLine());
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Hello world";
            StreamReader a = GetYAMLAsStreamReader(s);
            UseStreamReader1(a);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a `StringBuilder` and pass that around:

```
var contents = new StringBuilder(yamlFile);
return contents;
```

Comment: that's an interesting idea, and one I hadn't thought of.  the question though is more why passing  a StreamReader around sets EndOfStream to true.